# Bug in Calculator that finds your score needed to pass the class

Tags: android, kotlin

I am working on a project that inputs your current grade, goal for grade, and weight of final, and you receive what you need to get on your final. I am having issues with the correct math to figure out what you need to get on your final to get the grade you want.

```
`var goal by remember { mutableStateOf( "") }
 var currentGrade by remember { mutableStateOf( "") }
 var finalWeight by remember { mutableStateOf( "") }
 var finalGradeNeeded by remember { mutableStateOf("") }


 if (goal.isNotEmpty() && currentGrade.isNotEmpty() && finalWeight.isNotEmpty()) {
    if (finalWeight.toInt() == 0) {
        finalGradeNeeded = "Error: Cannot divide by zero"
    } else {
        finalGradeNeeded = ((goal.toDouble() - ((100 - finalWeight.toDouble()) *  (currentGrade.toDouble() / (finalWeight.toDouble() / 100))))).toString()
    }
}

Text(
    text = "Your final grade needs to be: $finalGradeNeeded%",
    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
    f`ontSize = 15.sp
)
```

When I input the current grade as 50, goal for class as a 50, and the final weight as 50, I expect it to be 50, but the output is -4950.0%.

Comment: In a debugger or on a piece of paper, plug the numbers into the `finalGradeNeeded` calculation and see where you went wrong.

Comment: I have tried that and feel dumb I cannot figure it out. With this code, if I input my goal as 70, my current grade as 100, and my weight for final as 50, I should get 40 as the answer, but instead I get 69%

                `finalGradeNeeded = (goal.toInt() - ((100 - finalWeight.toInt())* currentGrade.toInt()) / finalWeight.toInt() / 100).toString()`

Answer (score 1):

Simple weighted grading works like this:

```
(currentWeight * currentGrade) + (finalWeight * finalGrade) = weightedGrade
```

the parentheses are there just so it's easier to see the individial components, you don't actually need them there.

---

So we need to get the `finalGrade` variable on the left and everything else on the right side of the equation;

```
finalWeight * finalGrade = weightedGrade - (currentWeight * currentGrade)
```

```
finalGrade = (weightedGrade - currentWeight * currentGrade) / finalWeight
```

Also, just like you did in your code, the `currentWeight` in this example is equal to `1 - finalWeight` assuming the weights are in decimal notation, so the final formula for the `finalGrade` would be:

```
finalGrade = (weightedGrade - (1 - finalWeight) * currentGrade) / finalWeight
```

From here you should be able to implement this formula in your code.

---

There's also an edge case when the `finalGrade` necessary to reach the desired `weightedGrade` is larger than 100 and in that case you might want to warn the user.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I still seem to not have it right. Can you tell what is different from what you typed?

`finalGradeNeeded = ((goal.toInt() - (100 - finalWeight.toInt()) * currentGrade.toInt()) / finalWeight.toInt()).toString()`

Comment: What are the exact inputs you are testing with?

Comment: I am having a user input 3 different numbers in textfields, one for the goal they want their grade to be, another for the current grade, and the last is the final weight.

Comment: Yeah but what number values are you testing with

Comment: goal = 70, current grade = 90, and weight = 25. The expected output should be 10% I believe, but my app produces 89.2%

Comment: Oh. The problem is the grade weight value. The weight you are using is represented as a percentage, while I thought you would be using a decimal value like 0.25 . Dividing `finalWeight.toInt()` by 100 in both places it's used should fix it. You might also have to change the 100 to 1

Comment: Do you mean like this? `finalGradeNeeded = ((goal.toDouble() - (1 - finalWeight.toDouble()) * currentGrade.toDouble()) / finalWeight.toDouble()/100).toString()`

Comment: `finalGradeNeeded = ((goal.toDouble() - (1 - finalWeight.toDouble()/100) * currentGrade.toDouble()) / finalWeight.toDouble()/100).toString()`

Comment: that ends up saying if i use the same inputs as above, that my final grade needs to be 0.001%

Comment: Ah, the order of operations was wrong. The last section of the code where you divide final weight by 100 should be wrapped in parenthesis. Try this `finalGradeNeeded = ((goal.toDouble() - (1 - finalWeight.toDouble()/100) * currentGrade.toDouble()) / (finalWeight.toDouble()/100)).toString()`

Comment: That worked! I appreciate your help. Cannot believe I couldn't figure out PEMDAS lol